# For a non negative continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1]$ prove $\exists$ a positive function continuous $g(x)$ on $[0,1]$ satisfying;

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$g(x)=e^{-g(x)}+f(x)$

I intuitively would think this to be true, would showing the existence of fixed points help me prove this or is there a simple way to show this to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to the following: show that the equation

$$y - e^{-y} = a$$

has a positive solution for any $a \ge 0$. That is indeed the case. In fact, define the function $h : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by

$$h(y) = y-e^{-y}.$$

$h$ is continuous, strictly increasing ($h'(y) = 1+ e^{-y} > 0$), $h(0) = -1<0$ and $h(1) = 1- \frac{1}{e} >0$. Therefore it has a unique positive zero $y_0$. Therefore, $h$ takes, in the interval $(y_0, +\infty)$ any positive value and so the equation

$$y-e^{-y} = a$$

has a (unique) positive solution for any $a \ge 0$.

**Note:** You don't need to use the continuity of $f$. You do if you ask $g$ to be continuous, too.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out I forgot to require g to be continuous as well

Comment: So an acceptable proof could use the composite function h(g(x)) ? I am still a little confused as to how we can define a the derivative at 0 of the composite function as you did in your solution with constants

Comment: I am not using the composite function. Just fix $x$ so $a = f(x)$ and your corresponding $g(x)$ is the solution of the equation as above. Then you have your function $g$ at each point, with the required properties. 

Then you write $h(g(x))= f(x)$, and so $g(x) = h^{-1}(f(x))$, which implies $g$ continuous.

Comment: aaaa yes thankyou